# How to proof probability property?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Proof that P(A|B)+P(A|~B) = 1?
Can you help me to find probability properties to use?

~B = not B

Comment: @Masacroso: I believe it should be $$\mathrm{P}[A|B]\,\mathrm{P}[B]+\mathrm{P}[A|\lnot B]\,\mathrm{P}[\lnot B]=\mathrm{P}[A]$$ Consider $$\mathrm{P}[A|A]+\mathrm{P}[A|\lnot A]=1+0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by $B^{\prime}$ you mean the complement of $B$, then this identity does not hold in general.

For instance, suppose that you flip a fair coin twice, and that $A$ is the event that both flips are heads, while $B$ is the event that the first flip is heads. Then
$$ \mathbb{P}(A|B)+\mathbb{P}(A|B^c)=\frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Giving a single counterexample is enough to show a statement is false.

Comment: How can we strongly prove that formula is incorrect?
Using Law of Total Probability I came to this result:
P[A] = P[B|A]*P[A]+P[B|¬A]*P[¬A] ; P[B|A]=P[BA]/P[A] and P[B|¬A] = P[B*¬A]/P[¬A]. So P[B] = P[BA]+P[B*¬A] and i don't know what to do next

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by strongly prove. As I said, a counterexample suffices to show that a claimed formula is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, consider two independent events. An example:

Rolling a dice, and then rolling it again. Then $B$ denotes getting a $1$ on the first dice roll and $A$ is the random variable mapping dice outcomes to probabilities (that is $\frac{1}{6}$). Clearly the sum of these is NOT $1$. (that is the probability of getting a rolling some $x$ given that you rolled $1$).